# How to hide the button keeping the position?

Tags: css

I have this example and I would like to fix the position of the field when the info button won´t be active.

[image]

How to do this in css?

In the view I am creating dinamically this field with this code, calling correctly when I generate the form..

```
generateInfoForField: function (f, infoText) {
    return {
      xtype : 'container',
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
      },
      items : [
        f,
        {
          xtype    : 'button',
          cls      : 'infoText',
          iconCls  : 'info',
          infoText : infoText,
          itemId   : 'infoText',
          listeners: {
            tap: {
              scope: this,
              fn   : this.infoButtonTapped
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

And the css class is:

```
.infoText {
  margin-top: .3em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

Comment: Just make the inactive button invisible using "visibility:hidden".

Comment: If you only want to 'hide'  an element but have it's size/etc still influence the other parts of the page flow, you may want to use a "visibility:hidden"  tag in Css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting
`visibility: hidden;` to your button when it should be hidden. This way it still takes up the space needed, so the other elements' position will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see some code, but without this, the normal method to achieve something like this would be to give the child element **position: absolute;** and the parent element **position: relative;**.

In this context the parent element would likely be the bar itself, with the children being the decimal text, the input and the info button. You would need to absolutely position the info button, relatively position the bar and then place the info button in the correct position using the top and right css properties.